# Coupling View and Controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, controller

First i have a very basic Question about coupling two input Elements. In my case it is a Slider and an input element:

```
<div class="userInput">
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100"/>
    <input id="number" type="number" max="100"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#slider').corresponding = $('#number');
$('#number').corresponding = $('#slider');
$('#slider').onchange(function(){this.corresponding.value = this.value;});
$('#number').onchange(function(){this.corresponding.value = this.value;});
```

So this works for me but also seems to me like a dirty hack, extending the jQuery object. The bad feeling even grows when appending the controller to jQuery Objects:

```
var MYController = new Controller();
$('#slider').controller = MYController;
$('#slider').onchange(function(){
    this.corresponding.value = this.value; 
    this.controller.sliderChange(this.value);
});
```

I would appreciate any suggestions how this is done "the right way". I couldn't figure out a better way yet because i have a large and changing number of user inputs, each requiring its own controller Object, held in an array in my Mastercontroller Class.

Comment: well, i've come to the conclusion that this is - basically - the way i have to do it. Looking at Backbonejs i have come to the conclusion that they are doing it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put all the inputs inside a `<form></form>` tag in jsp and then call the form submit event or the serialize event. With the latter (serialize any value stored against a button would not be stored and it would need the name attribute in the jsp tags as well, so may be submit is a better option).

```
//jsp page
<form id="myForm" >
<input type="text" value="Enter here">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

//js call
( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
// call the controller
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This could be a workaround but i would loose the responsiveness of my solution. It is absolutely necessary to let the user instantly see the results of his input.